# statusbar reappears after screen off

Tags: android, locking, fullscreen, unlock

my android app is displayed fullscreen.
to be 100% sure I did this in code with:

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   setContentView(R.layout.findperson);
```

and in xml with 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

whenever my screen turns off for power saving, and i turn it back on again, the statusbar is back and does not want to disappear. How can i make it disappear forever (or for the duration of my app)?

edit:
okay, i did find some more info this:
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);

interferes with the fullscreen setting.

I know we are not "supposed to" override the homebutton. However, I am desiging an app that is exclusively used on the phone. in other words, the phone should lose its phone function and only show this app.